# What is the meaning of "provision of a service"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I could not understand the phrase *provision of a service* in the sentence below:

More specifically, they provide us with insight into the mechanisms behind the emergence of reciprocal altruism, a social interaction involving the exchange of favors in which there is a temporal delay between the **provision of a service** and its reciprocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can **divide** a number, or we can  **divide** an apple so that it can be shared between two people.

When we wish to refer to the act of **dividing**, the abstract noun is  **division**.  *Division of the apple into two pieces*.

We can **provide** a service (perform the service for those who pay for it, e.g. dog walking, house cleaning, data center management, etc.). When we wish to refer to the act of **providing**, the abstract noun is **provision**.  *Provision of service*.

*Division.  Provision.*

Answer (score 4):

Provision means providing...  from Google Dictionary

> noun
>   1. the action of providing or supplying something for use. "new contracts for the provision of services" synonyms:    supplying, supply,
>   providing, giving, presentation, donation; More
>   2. an amount or thing supplied or provided. "low levels of social provision" synonyms:    facilities, services, amenities, resource(s),
>   arrangements; More verb
>   1. supply with food, drink, or equipment, especially for a journey. "civilian contractors were responsible for provisioning these armies"
>   2. set aside an amount in an organization's accounts for a known liability. "financial institutions have to provision against loan
>   losses"

Answer (score 3):

This means: ...delay between the (time when) *a service is provided* and its reciprocation.